# How to remove a legend for a series from dojo chart

Tags: charts, dojo

I have a dojo chart with a vertical line series, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450690/add-a-line-not-a-series-to-a-dojo-chart).  How do I remove this series from the legend so that only my 'real' series are shown in the legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
chart1.removeSeries("vertical line");  //Removes the series from the chart by series name
chart1.render();   //Refresh the chart
legend.refresh();  //Refresh the dojo legend object to update it
```

Comment: That's the solution I came up with.  Remove Series, update legend, put series back. But; it does seem rather inelegant.